# Handle SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE in LocationServices settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

On Android 7 what could be the reason that LocationServices.SettingsApi gives SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE?

And also what to do to enable location in such a case? Is there a way to to that in application or should I just display a dialog to user that he should manually enable locations?

I used also this sample to check it and it always go to SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

There they only show a message to user.

So questions:

1. What is the (possible) reason why it is failing?
2. Is there a way to enable location from the app not using settings api?